# Match last instance of px; with RegEx

Tags: regex, excel, libreoffice-calc

I am looking to match the last instance of px; with Regex for the string below

si="29" ] { top:340px; left:194px;

How can I use the Find/Replace with Regex ticked in Libreoffice (Excel)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but how about:

Search for: `^.*top:\d+px; left:(\d+)px;$`

Replace with: `$1`

(I would however recommend using other tools for this kind of text processing, such as `sed` - it will make things much simpler and you'll get more help.)

Comment: When the search matches, I am looking to append a } to the last occurance of px; (so in this case 194px;)

Comment: I'd try for example `^(.*top:\d+px; left:\d+px;)$`, then replace with `$1 }`